# Is there a way to make while True loop to show randomly in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm really new in Coding, with Python.
I was trying to make a Vocabulary exercise program for a Language that i am learning it right now. So the concept is, if the word "abhängen" is shown at the Console, i have to write "von" which is the right word to come after that word, which is "abhängen". And the program will show if its right or wrong, and loops the input to get the right answer.
But since there are tons of vocabulary, i have to make same loop over and over again just by using while True and changing a,b,c for the variables and the word between "". Is there a way to make it shorter maybe by using list or something?

And if its possible, can i somehow make the order of the questions randomly? Since this code always shows the first question as abhängen and second as abrechnen.

Sorry if this was some kind of dumb question to ask, have nowhere to ask haha
have a nice day guys

```
while True:
    a = input("abhängen ")
    if a == "von":
        print("You're right")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong")

while True:
    c = input("abrechnen ")
    if c == "mit":
        print("You're right")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Comment: You can do it with a single loop and something that holds the body of questions and answers, like a list of tuples (e.g. `[ ("abhängen", "mit"), ...]`, a dict of question-to-answer (e.g. `{ "abrechnen": "mit", "abhängen": "von" }`), etc. You can also put the question-answer portion in its own method and give it arguments for question and expected answer.

Comment: I'll try to figure out what is list of tuples, thanks!

Comment: Should start here if you're not familiar with the basic data structures of Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: thanks, ill see that through and learn some more basics haha

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a great example to learn usage of lists in Python.

You can use list of tuples and `random` module for this task. See `random.shuffle` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
words_and_answers = [("abhängen ", "von"), ("abrechnen ", "mit")]

random.shuffle(words_and_answers)

for input_word, correct_answer in words_and_answers:
  while True:
    user_response = input(input_word)
    if user_response == correct_answer:
      print("You're right")
      break
    else:
      print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Hey, if you are still looking this, i just ran this code at Python and it works perfectly! But i have one question, when i ran this, it magically pops the word "abhängen" so that i can write the matching next word, but where is the code that prints the word "abhängen"?? I have no idea how it poped out, since i only see print ("You're right") and ("Wrong")

Comment: The line `user_response = input(input_word)` does it. 
`input_word` contains text that would pop to the screen, and `input()` function at the same time: pops the text and waits for users input.  Checkout [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Aha, so the line ```for input_word, correct_answer in words_and_answers:``` defines the list``` [("abhängen ", "von"), ("abrechnen ", "mit")]``` that "abhängen" is the input_word and "von" is the correct_answer? and the line under which is user_response = input(input_word) prints out the word and wait for the input at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution is to use a dictionary in which the keys are the words "abhängen", "abrechnen", ecc... And the values are the correct words that come after. So you can write a thing like this:

```
vocabulary = {
    "abhängen" : "von",
    "abrechnen" : "mit"
}

for i in vocabulary:
    a = input(i + " ")
    if a == vocabulary[i]:
        print("You are right")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Note that in this case the loop is not infinite! This method allows you to have more than one word correct for each key

For the randomly access to the keys, you can make a list with the keys and use the random.shuffle() method, like this:

```
import random

keys = list(vocabulary.keys())
random.shuffle(keys)
```

And then your loop will be:

```
for i in keys:
    ...
```

Comment: ah yeah this can also be a solution! Thanks! Ill write something down if i don't understand something